# Django status field

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a function when the customer enters the scheduled date and updates the form the status of the form changes to Scheduled. However I'm unable to change it back to another status without deleting the scheduled date.I want my fucntion to be able to change the status without deleting scheduled_date

```
views.py
def update_order(request, pk):
     order = Order.objects.filter(id=pk).first()
     form = OrderForm(request.POST or None, user=request.user,instance=order)
     if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save(commit=False)
            order.updated_by = request.user
            order.date_updated = timezone.now()
            if order.scheduled_date is not None:
                order.status = 'Scheduled'
            order.save()
            form.save()
            return redirect('/orderlist/')
     context = {'form':form}
     t_form = render_to_string('update_form.html', context, request=request,
                )

     return JsonResponse({'t_form': t_form})
```

```
class Order(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.IntegerField(max_length=11) = models.DateField(max_length=100, null=True)
    status_choices = (('Received', 'Received'),
        ('Scheduled', 'Scheduled'), 
        ('Shipped','Shipped'),
        )
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = status_choices, default="In Progress")
```

Answer (score 1):

First return the order instance with `commit=False` then procees your logic with the instance and finally save the object in the database.

```
form = OrderForm(request.POST or None, user=request.user,instance=order)
     if form.is_valid():
        order = form.save(commit=False)
        order.updated_by = request.user
        order.date_updated = timezone.now()
        if order.scheduled_date:
             order.status = form.cleaned_data.get('status', 'Scheduled')
        order.save()
        return redirect....
```

Comment: What does the other status mean ? Can you give example

Comment: You are not following the answer correctly.just do `order.save()` outside the if condition